# android and ie7 css positioning issue

Tags: android, css, internet-explorer-7

I've just launched a new version of our site and I'm trying to iron out a few issues which I wasn't able to test before because I can't emulate an android phone on my localhost (I'm sure it's possible - time didn't allow the required reading)

Anyway, I tested on ie7-9, ff, opera, safari, chrome, everything you can think of an mostly everything is just fine apart from:

on android phone: I have a horizontal navigation bar between the header and the content, the last item on the menu has shifted to the next line. This could be just a pixel, but why! why! why! boohoo :(

Then on IE7, on any page which has lots of products (like this one: http://www.traditionalirishgifts.com/guinness-merchandise) the filter options and the paging navigation are meant to be on one line, like they are on every other browser.

any css genius's out there fancy helping me out?

Comment: image plz. and some code if u can ???

Comment: Try giving a width to #perpagecontainer and #sortordercontainer.

Comment: @omarj the site is online so you can see the code and what it looks like. If you go to traditionalirishgifts.com you can see it.

Comment: I've solved the IE7 problem by just omitting the javascript that was making the dropdown boxes look nice on IE7. But my problem with android (and ipad apparently) persists. Does anyone know if there's a specific android/ipad rendering issue I should be looking for?

Comment: You should put some code, css or something. Other option is just to fix it with another style just for that DIV and Android.

Comment: @pleerock, the url is there, I didn't think screen shots would add much :) Still having the problem though about the 'price range' text falling down a line below the horizontal nav bar (which apparently dosn't drop down in ipad/iphone at all) Still having major headaches with this. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: @sandeep I use a css reset already.

Comment: Note the another bug with styled checkboxes. When page is loaded and then browser window is resized they just stick at their places as if absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It depends on the screen resolution of the phone. If you tried it
   on a phone with a wider screen in pixels, you would have no problem.
2. I see one IE7 problem:

> `div#dropMenu` no specified padding

IE7 has a default padding unlike any modern browser.

Add `padding: 0` and you will have no problems.

Comment: Hi @giantduck (cool name by the way) the problem (1) of the navbar I don't think has to do with the screen resolution. I've tried it on an ipad and the problem is there too. The ipad has a big enough screen. Any other ideas?

Comment: (0)Thanks

(1)if the screen resolution is too narrow, then the navigation `li`s will overhang and cause a second row. If it is an original iPad or an iPad 2, the screen resolution can be smaller than an iPhone 5 (which has more than 2x as many PPI [pixels per inch])

(2) Does specifying `padding: 0px` fix in IE 7 for you?

Comment: How can I fix problem 1? problem 2 isn't an issue anymore. Regarding Problem 1: If I set my desktop to a screen resolution of 800x600 it doesn't cause the price range to drop down. Very weird. Your seem very smart, any clues?

Comment: A smartphone can have a screen width of anything from less than 400px to 1000px+. Thus why many websites have m.example.com for mobile devices.

Comment: On further investigation it seems that only android 2 and below have the problem no matter what size the screen width is.

Comment: Tried to load the page in default Android 2.3 browser, but don't see any issues with brown menu in header. Have you sorted it out?